# Hive JDBC connection is not happening through JMeter

Tags: performance, hive, jmeter, load-testing, apache-phoenix

[JDBC connection config details are provided as per QA envirnoment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNmfs.png)

[provided the queries details for fetching the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWYhJ.png)

[facing errors while fetching the details, Please help me here , I have added all necessary jar files which is the latest updated versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjtWx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Hive JDBC driver source](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveConnection.java#L888):

```
  Utils.verifySuccess(openResp.getStatus());
  if (!supportedProtocols.contains(openResp.getServerProtocolVersion())) {
    throw new TException("Unsupported Hive2 protocol");
  }
```

it seems that your JDBC driver version doesn't match the server-side version, you need to download **exactly** the same version of the JDBC driver which matches your server installation.

If you cannot figure out the correct version of server you can [enable debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for Hive JDBC driver and inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any clues.

In the meantime you can try use `hive` instead of `hive2` in the JDBC URL, however it might have negative impact to the results as they won't be that realistic